# Data Extract File Convert activity throwing error

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, data-extract

While converting File format from UTF-16le to UTF-8 in Automation studio using Data Extract (File Convert), I am getting error but not able to understand what error is coming as Automation Studio doesn't show any error message.

I have starting activity which extracts the data from DE and in next step I want to convert the file encoding to UTF-8 as SFMC default encoding is UTF-16.

So kindly help in providing solution.

[image: Below image is the File Convert configuration done in Automation Data Extract Activity]

Comment: unfortunately that is a custom extract and thus you will get no official support. I've had it work and not work myself. My strategies to test were: Make 100% sure that your file is in safehouse. (e.g. test your process with a file transfer that surfaces the file, then replace the file transfer again with file convert and rerun). Make sure your filenames match incl. file ending and try to avoid the date placeholders. I believe %%year%% %%month%% %%day%% are supported but first try without them.

Comment: You could try using another custom extract type for this, “Data Extension Extract with File Encoding and gzip” (gzipping's optional). It can do the extraction of the records from a Data Extension to a UTF-8 encoded file in a single step and is a little more intuitive to use than the File Convert extract. BTW, the encoding of Data Extension extracts employs the now obsolete UCS-2 standard, rather than the newer UTF-16 standard. Many modern tools interpret these files incorrectly as UTF-16 and make a mess of the Byte Order Mark at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @JonasLamberty - Thanks for the reply. I will work on your solution and try it and get back to you with some positive result.

Comment: @Macca - Thanks for the reply. I will try your solution and get to back with some positive result.