# File convert to UTF8

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, data-views, data-extract, convert

I'm trying to extract the journeys data with data views and put the generated file in FTP with UTF format.

After configuring the query and the Data extract activity (Data extract from Data extension), I added the File convert activity to the automation :

[image]

When I run the automation, an error is occured in the File convert Activity and as there is no logs, I don't know what's the problem.

Can you help me please ? Thank you in advance!

Regards,

Ilyass

Comment: Check suggestions in the comments from this question, there is nothing more to add - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/317523/data-extract-file-convert-activity-throwing-error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the file name pattern. When using "%%Minute%%%%Seconds%%", by the time the first Activity ends and then the second activity starts, the file pattern will not match because of the Seconds and Minutes. I tried without minutes and seconds and it works.

Thank you!